# I got An EOFError while doing a project and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, eoferror

[Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaKcD.png)[Assignment/code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kBVb.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ccae.png) [code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ1cf.png)[code3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76u8i.png)

```
if __name__ == '__main__': # Do not modify
    # FiLL array with five dice from input
    dice = [int(val) for val in input().split()]
    high_score = 0
    # PLace dice in ascending order
    dice.sort()
    print(dice)
    # Find high score and output
    high_score = find_high_score(dice)
    print("High score:", high_score)
```

Here is the Trace back
-***"Traceback*** (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 83, in 
**dice = [int(val) for val in input().split()]**
EOFError: **EOF when reading a line"**

Im kind of at a lost here so please help my guess us is that this might be a raw_input()function that why the code my not be working. please look at the link above as it contains more information Also beginner in python so please explain in simple words. thank you

Comment: Please include the full traceback message and indicate which line of code is triggering it (it gives the line number in the traceback but that doesn't mean we will know which it is from the small segment shown in your question).

Comment: First of all, please transcribe the image so people don't have to follow a link for the error code. Second, are you providing any input? The image suggests you are not, and the program is erroring because it is getting an EOF instead of a value. There is red text that says "your program expects input" but the box is empty.

Comment: This code works fine on my system, assuming all that `find_high_score(dice)` does is `return max(dice)`. You must not be entering input correctly in whatever web interface you are using

Comment: Are you running this using an online code submission service?  In such an environment, `input()` generally will not work unless you specifically provide input before running the code.  I'm sure your service has some way of doing this.

Comment: Using zybooks for running the code also more info above

Comment: I have found out the issue turn out I Wasn't typing the inputs in and also the code was correct was just too dumb not to see it. also because i was using zybooks to run the input, they just wanted the HIGH_SCORE while i was giving them the HIGH_SCORE and The DICE NUMBER that was not needed. Anyways thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with this code. The first is that there is no call to the find_high_score function. Also, the find_high_score function is not defined anywhere in the code. This means that the code will throw a name error when trying to call the function.

Another problem is that the code reads user input but does not validate it in any way. If the user enters less than five numbers, or if the numbers entered are not valid (for example, if they are negative numbers or greater than 6), the code will also throw an error.

To fix these problems, you must add the find_high_score function definition and call it correctly in the code. Additionally, you must validate input to ensure that the user enters exactly five valid numbers.

Comment: Provide more information above. it shows the assignment and the code used

Assignment Assignment/code code code2code3